# UART communication, is it possible to use only the TX line?

Tags: arduino-mega, esp8266, uart

I am trying to connect an *ESP-01* with an *ArduinoMega* through the **serial** port of both, as they use different voltage levels I would need a voltage divider between the TX pin of the Mega (pin 1) and the pin RX of the ESP-01 (pin 4) , it is not difficult to do, but I just need to *"send data"* from *ESP-01* to *Mega*, then I have a question and it is as follows:

If I just need to **send** data from one device to the other, could I just connect the **TX** pin of the *ESP-01* to the **RX** of the *Mega*? If I do so, will I receive data in the Mega?

Greetings

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I tried using an FTDItoUSB for the ESP-01, it didn't work for me...the answer that give me back (Arduino IDE and PuTTY) is: "Unable to open PORT4. PORT4 is in use".

Comment: OS reporting that the port in use, has nothing to do with what is actually connected to RX and TX pins.

Comment: A PC operating system complaint that a port is in use would have nothing to do with the question you posted, but merely be an incidental problem in the course of usage.  Try closing any programs that might use serial communication, including the arduino IDE, serial monitor, tools like putty, defunct instances of avrdude, etc.

Comment: I tried restarting the PC (in this scenarios I use Windows) for any rare program, then I tried again using the same configuration, the same result.

Comment: the esp-01 will not blow if you connect 5 V logic to it. the io pins are 5 V tolerant. maybe not for long term, but sure for some tests. has this esp-01 some bigger value for you, that you are so cautious?

Comment: Yeap, I'm in Cuba and this pieces of technology from "outter space" are veryyyyy difficult to have. If some day you came here, let me know :)

Comment: It works! Just (in my case) the TX pin from the ESP goes to the TX pin from the Mega, I don't know why, but work in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

You can connect only the the line with which the ESP-01 *transmits* to the Arduino's receiver, and accomplish one-way data transfer.

*However*, the ESP will have to be willing to transmit without prompting, and you will not be able to use the Arduino to setup or configure it.  Further, you will not be able to use any in-band signalling to ask the ESP to refrain from sending, so you will have to be sure that your Arduino sketch is generally ready to claim any input which may arrive, and that if there are periods when it is not, the behind-the-scenes serial buffer is large enough.

There's also the question if it is safe to connect the ESP transmit pin directly to the Arduino receive.  In the intended direction of operation, it is.  But should you ever load code on the Arduino which uses that pin as a GPIO output, there is some risk of damage to the ESP.  It's up to you to decide if careful usage will be enough to prevent that; if not, you may want to try something like a 1K series resistor and a schottky diode to clamp the line to the ESP's 3.3v supply, in a way that diverts the current from any accidental 5v output around any internal protection diode that may have more limited power handling.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and for the recommendations! You just give the tips that I was looking for! I just want to connect my phone to the *ESP*, open any browser and send some data (*a color code, wich is just hexadecimal codes*), the *ESP* recieve that data and send to the *Mega*, the *Mega* then will select from the hexa-code the color to set to some leds (50 leds from WS2812B led strip). Do you think the serial buffer from the *Mega* can hold this? And all this for don't put just to resistences!!! :-)

Comment: If you don't hammer it with constant requests, yes.  Do note that receiving multi-character strings can take a little care - you might consider adding a terminating newline as a definitive end marker, and then using line-oriented input.

Comment: Sorry for for the unknow but: what do you mean when you say: "terminating newline" and "line-oriented input".

Comment: Essentially it means typing a value and then hitting the return key, or having a program do so.  This is more deterministic than sending a value and having the Arduino merely wait until it decides you are not going to type any more digits.   You could rig this up with Serial.readBytesUntil() and atoi() but it will require some work.  Unfortunately, the built-in turnkey methods like Serial.parseInt() use the less reliable timeout approach.  Still many seem to manage using those.  You can also see if sending a newline helps parseInt() finish more promptly.

Comment: Ok, I got what you say...is like have the Mega waiting for the character "\n", meaning a new line, and then download all you have in the bus of the serial to a variable. Is that what you want to say? Another question come to me: can I use *RegularExpresions* (regex) in the Mega?

Comment: There are no doubt libraries for regular expression that you can use and at the scale you want to use they would likely be workable, but it might be preferable to avoid the need for such heavy string processing on the little tiny Arduino.   Can you clean up the data on the ESP side (or even at the network source) and only send the more Arduino a clean command, like "123\n" ?

Comment: Yeap I think that you're rigth, thanks for the directions you gave to me!!!